# In a div containing 3 paragraphs can I use CSS Pseudo-elements like after and before to change the p tag to the span tag

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="titles">
  <p> title1</p>
  <p> title2</p>
  <p> title3</p>
</div>
```

div title is our container here the 3 paragraphs inside need to be replaced with the span tag
is that possible doing this with only html and css

Comment: Nope pseudo element can't permit to change a tag to another however via CSS you can modify the appearance of a p so that it looks like a span, example:
p {
  display: inline;
}

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot change a tag using CSS. You can change the behaviour, like display:inline for the Ps or display:block for the SPANs

```css
#titles p {
  display: inline;
}
#spans span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="titles">
  <p>title1</p>
  <p>title2</p>
  <p>title3</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="spans">
  <span>title1</span>
  <span>title2</span>
  <span>title3</span>
</div>
```